# Word wrapping orphans quotes when first character in quotes is a <

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

This very well may be a Chrome bug, but the following three character sequences:

- `"<`
- `` "`<` ``
- `"&lt;`

Allow word wrapping to insert a line break after the `"`. It does not seem to matter if the quoted text is in backticks. But, weirdly, I could not reproduce it with any other character but `<` (for example `">` does not have this issue).

Examples:

> [image]

Suggested fix (or workaround if it's a Chrome issue):

Have the Markdown renderer insert a [word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) (`&#8288;`) after a quote if the next character (ignoring markup characters) is a `<` (or something else if there is a more appropriate Unicode character, but that's all I could find), or just in general after every quote to cover all cases. This appears to resolve all issues when tested against the examples above.